# How to add user assigned identity in azure sql using azure cli?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, identity-management

I want to do the following function using Azure CLI. turn the system assigned service principal off, Add a user managed identity and make it the primary identity using Azure CLI. Would much appreciate the help.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-azure-ad-user-assigned-managed-identity?view=azuresql#set-a-managed-identity-in-the-azure-portal

Comment: Could you please provide the error if any got?

Comment: I tried this: az sql mi update -g myResourceGroup -n myServer -i \ --user-assigned-identity-id /subscriptions/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/testumi \ --identity-type UserAssigned --pid /subscriptions/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/testumi

Comment: And error i got: unrecognized arguments:  --user-assigned-identity-id /subscriptions/*******************/*************/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/test_uim_sk  --identity-type UserAssigned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to replicate the issue in my environment with below code:

```
 az sql mi update -g Analytics-Resources -n sqlmanagedinstanceshared -i \ --user-assigned-identity-id /subscriptions/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/Analytics-Resources/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/dbm \ --identity-type UserAssigned --pid /subscriptions/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/Analytics-Resources/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/dbm
```

I got the same error:

[image]

This error I got because of extra back slash at -i I removed that tried to exucute the code:

```
az sql mi update -g Analytics-Resources -n sqlmanagedinstanceshared -i  --user-assigned-identity-id /subscriptions/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/Analytics-Resources/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/dbm \ --identity-type UserAssigned --pid /subscriptions/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/Analytics-Resources/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/dbm
```

The error was resolved, and it executed successfully.

[image]